# Creating a search box by combining two tables compared to a specific keyword

Tags: mysql, laravel, union

Hellow can you please help me? I am trying to combine two tables which has no relation at all except some field, but  the main ideas is:

- Union the two tables
- look for items that contains "code" on it's fields.
  but there is always and error saying that

> #1054 - Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

```
 SELECT role ,id,'' as type, '' as logo, username,'' as contactperson, lastname, '' as        companyname, firstname, '' as address, description, address FROM users 
 UNION
 SELECT '' as role, id,type, logo,'' as username, contactperson, '' as lastname,     companyname, '' as firstname, address, description, website FROM company
 WHERE type LIKE '%code%'
 OR logo LIKE '%code%'
 OR username LIKE '%code%'
 OR contactperson LIKE '%code%'
 OR lastname LIKE '%code%'
 OR companyname LIKE '%code%'
 OR firstname LIKE '%code%'
 OR address LIKE '%code%'
 OR description LIKE '%code%'
OR address LIKE '%code%')
```

I know my code seems overkill, please help me out? or posts same as my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of your table using `union` is not a good idea. It is better to use join based on few matching columns between these two tables and create new table and perform your search on the new table. For example [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6f2/1).

To answer your issue, prefix `username` with `users`.

Example:
`users.username LIKE '%code%'`

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i'll try this one at home.